# My ionic app is not working on ios 10?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have added the below meta tag in index.html still my app is not working on ios 10? when i build on native device it is showing only splashscreen..

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap://ready file://* *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

Comment: What does the error console say?

Comment: first am getting this error : Refused to load gap://ready because it appears in neither the child-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.   After addding the above meta tag nothing error is not showing only splashscreen came..

Comment: When i run using ionic serve it's working all functionality..

Comment: Strange, are you testing on a real device? try hitting "refresh" i safari dev tools while debugging on the device and check the console again.

Comment: Are you running from xcode? what does the console in xCode say? any errors?

Comment: Thats just a mess... is there any actual errors?

Comment: i didn't get error in x-code console

Comment: With no errors to debug I can't help you. Maybe someone else knows about this.

Comment: Hi @iCediCe  I am getting the safari dev console error is Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.connection.type') what should i do?? i used in my app like 
                var state = navigator.connection.type;
                if (state !== window.Connection.NONE) {                   
                  alert('yes');                   
                } else {
                    alert('No);
                }
am used the plugin in my app is cordova-plugin-network-information and one more thing is in app.js $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {alert('ready)}) is not firing

Comment: Sound really strange that $ionicPlatform.ready is not firering. But if your call to network info is not wrapped thats properly the cause. You need to figure out why $ionicPlatform.ready is not firering.

Comment: then what i have to do?? could you say me the solution to figure out $ionicPlatform.ready..

Comment: What cordova and ionic versions are you on? what does 'ionic info' say? Try updating.

Comment: Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.2
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.2
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 
Node Version: v6.9.1

Comment: Hmm. looks ok. There is lots of info about why ionic.ready might not fire. try here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionicplatform-ready-not-firing-on-device-ios/41739 and use google. If you do not resolve the issue create a new stackoverflow question and post your code.

Comment: ok thanks...@iCediCe

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the Content Security Policy as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * android-webview-video-poster: 'self' data:; default-src * 'self' gap: wss: ws: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

Does this resolve your issue?

Comment: Mh, I'm sorry to hear that.. found this example project though, prepared by someone who had the same issue you're describing. Maybe compare your index.html against [the one in this project](https://github.com/cballock/ionic-geolocation/blob/master/www/index.html). Otherwise this is indeed hard to debug without any further errors. Possibly post the header of your index.html here in case you don't see any differences between your and the linked solution?

Comment: in this project the meta tag is like that :  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap: *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">